# Attaching treads to stringers when building deck stairs

Tags: deck, stairs

I have deck stairs with 2x10 treads attached to 2x10 stringers with 2x4 cleats. Should I also screw the treads in from outside the stringer? If so what fastener should I use.

Comment: I presume that the stringers are just 2x10 placed at an angle with the treads between them? i.e. there are no dados for the treads to slip into, nor are there cuts into the stringers for the treads or risers? A picture always helps, you can [edit] into your post (click the "sun & mountain" icon - the picture will be uploaded and hosted for you).

Comment: Not if your cleats are securely fastened. Revise to tell us about that.